# no `fileno()` function in nuwen.net MinGW Distro?

Tags: c++, mingw

this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << fileno(stdout) << endl;
}
```

Works fine in this compiler: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.7.2/32-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x32-4.7.2-release-posix-sjlj-rev6.7z

but in this package : http://nuwen.net/files/mingw/mingw-9.5-without-git.exe

it returns: `test.cpp:5:24: error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileno` is not part of C or C++, but [is POSIX](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno). Therefore it has no place on Windows. To write portable code, stick to the features provided by the C and C++ standards.

That's probably why they don't ship it in a GCC port for Windows. By contrast, the POSIX threads implementation you linked to likely relies on it as an implementation detail to keep the ported code as similar as possible to the original code.

Any further rationale is subjective and off-topic; in short, you'd have to ask *them*!

Comment: This answer is nonsense. MinGW is a "GNU Environment". Though it is "minimal", it has an `isatty` function, which "has no place on Windows". How can you do `isatty(fileno(stdin))` if you do have `isatty` but no `fileno`?

Comment: Furthermore, there is evidence of `fileno` in the headers.

Answer (score 3):

MinGW has `fileno`. From my MinGW window:

```
$ grep -r fileno c:/mingw/include
c:/mingw/include/stdio.h:_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW    _fileno (FILE*);

c:/mingw/include/stdio.h:_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW    fileno (FILE*);
c:/mingw/include/stdio.h:#define _fileno(__F) ((__F)->_file)
c:/mingw/include/stdio.h:#define fileno(__F) ((__F)->_file)
```

Oops, unfortunately, the problem is that MinGW does something supremely idiotic. It makes the visibility of extensions to `stdio.h` (a library which has nothing to do with GCC)  the subject of GCC-specific dialect control flags.

Cygwin also has this problem, and in a discussion thread some years ago in the Cygwin mailing list, they vehemently denied that it is a problem.

The correct way is to have feature selection macros like `_POSIX_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and so on. (These macros have proliferated in recent years and have become more complicated.)

MinGW should obey `-D_POSIX_SOURCE` on the command line and reveal `fileno` even if `--ansi` is specified.

The way things are now, you have to compromise the language dialect and accept GCC extensions and non-compliances, just because you want POSIX function declarations to be visible.

**I have come up with a workaround, however, which doesn't involve doing anything ugly in the source code. Watch this:**

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -U__STRICT_ANSI__ foo.c -c
```

That's it. On MinGW, instead of using a feature selection macro like `-D_POSIX_SOURCE`, we use `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` to strip away GCC's macro.

I added a test to my `./configure` script to detect this broken situation and add `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` to the `CFLAGS`. Works like a charm in my project.

Comment: Using `-ansi -U__STRICT_ANSI__` means "I don't want extensions but please allow me to use extensions" which is silly. Just use `-std=gnu++03` or `-std=gnu++11` instead which doesn't set `__STRICT_ANSI__` in the first place.

Comment: @JohathanWakely: using `__STRICT_ANSI__` means "I'm inappropriately using/undefining an internal macro to obtain a desired effect, because the library designers do not understand feature selection macros."  I don't think `-std=gnu++03` is appropriate for my code that is written in C90. (Which is why I'm using `-ansi`: to request conformance to the C90 dialect.)

Comment: well then use `-std=gnu90` which requests the C90 dialect without defining `__STRICT_ANSI__`. By using `-std=c90` you've explicitly requested the mode that defines `__STRICT_ANSI__`, so don't blame the library designers for doing as asked

Comment: `-U__STRICT_ANSI__` worked nicely for me when compiling luafilesystem on MinGW.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanWakely `-std=c90` **with a** standard-defined feature selection flag like `_POSIX_SOURCE` means that the declaration of `fileno` must be visible in `<stdio.h>` in spite of the compiler's dialect being C90. Without any such feature selection, of course such extensions should be hidden.

Comment: @cxw Since this Q&A almost four years ago, I have abandoned MinGW. Cygwin DLL's are now LGPLed so they can be shipped under BSD licensed code as well as proprietary code. In the wake of this, I started the [Cygnal](http://kylheku.com/cygnal) project which gives native-like behaviors to the Cygwin DLL so it can be used as the run-time for Windows programs.

Comment: @Kaz and my point remains: if you don't want `__STRICT_ANSI__` to be defined, don't use the `-std=cNN` option that defines it. Using `-std=gnu90` instead of `-ansi` (which is a synonym for `-std=c90`) gives you the same base standard (C90) without defining `__STRICT_ANSI__`.

Comment: @Kaz thanks for the pointer!  Cygnal looks very useful.  My use case is installers, and I want to deploy a single .EXE without non-Windows DLL dependencies.  I'm still with MinGW for now :) .

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what compiler flags you're using, but this is probably happening because you're compiling with `-ansi`, which enforces strict ANSI compliance and disables the compatibility macros. (Or something like `-std=c99`, which implies `-ansi`.)

Try it without the `-ansi` or specifying a standard like `-std=gnu99` instead.

Comment: `-ansi` is a synonym for either `-std=c90` or `-std=c++98` (depending on the language being compiled) so it's not true that `-std=c99` implies -`ansi`, but it _does_ imply `__STRICT_ANSI__`, so you're right to suggest `-std=gnuXX`. The question's about C++ so the right option to get C++11 without disabling extensions is `-std=gnu++11`